# How to detect in real-time, whether there is an audio video sync or lag using FFMPEG?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, sync, streaming

I'm not asking about how to fix an audio video sync issue or lag. That I'll figure out, using FFMPEG's [timeline editing](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) filter. My question is about whether there is a way to detect if the audio and video are out of sync. The problem is, that when audio and video are streamed from Google Meet or Zoom, if one user has network latency or a low-hardware machine, that user's audio and video will be out of sync, while other participant's audio video will be in sync.

So if FFMPEG could detect at which point of the streamed video there is a lack of sync, I could use a dynamic filter condition to synchronize the audio and video. I'd assume it could be done via timestamps, but if it were that easy, FFMPEG could have done the synchronization automatically.

So how can the async issue be detected in realtime?